# Decoding XML String

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I am having trouble decoding some encoded xml.

I am getting "XmlException Unhandled: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1 Position 1"

```
<argo-response status="1" status-id="INFO">
  <messages>
    <message message-id="INFO" message-severity="INFO" message-text="[class-name:LBCTSubmitInGateDataWebService]" message-detail="[class-name:LBCTSubmitInGateDataWebService]" />
    <message message-id="GROOVY_RESULT" message-severity="INFO" message-text="Result: &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; ?&gt;&#xA;&lt;lbct:submit-ingate-data-response xmlns='(Had to remove link)' xmlns:xsi='(Had to remove link)' xmlns:lbct='(Had to remove link)' lbct:message-id='789637546382669' lbct:message-date='2014-01-23T06:37:32.0Z' lbct:facility-id='LBCT' lbct:complex-id='LBCT' lbct:sender='TOS'&gt;&#xA;  &lt;lbct:create-truck-visit-response&gt;&amp;lt;![CDATA[&amp;lt;argo:gate-response xmlns:argo=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=&quot(Had to remove link)&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;create-truck-visit-response&amp;gt;&amp;lt;truck-visit tv-key=&quot;52947590&quot; gos-tv-key=&quot;123&quot; tracking-tag-id=&quot;98765432&quot; is-internal=&quot;false&quot; next-stage-id=&quot;ingate&quot; status=&quot;OK&quot; gate-id=&quot;LBCT&quot; entered=&quot;2014-01-23T05:47:28&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;trucking-co id=&quot;WNWI&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;truck id=&quot;98765432&quot; tag-id=&quot;98765432&quot; license-nbr=&quot;D98765432&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;chassis-profile id=&quot;40&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;driver card-id=&quot;98765432&quot; driver-name=&quot;LICENSEABC&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/truck-visit&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/create-truck-visit-response&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/argo:gate-response&amp;gt;]]&amp;gt;&lt;/lbct:create-truck-visit-response&gt;&#xA;  &lt;lbct:process-truck-response&gt;&amp;lt;![CDATA[Unknown IN lane LANE20 for gate LBCT&amp;lt;argo:gate-response xmlns:argo=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;process-truck-response /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/argo:gate-response&amp;gt;]]&amp;gt;&lt;/lbct:process-truck-response&gt;&#xA;&lt;/lbct:submit-ingate-data-response&gt;" message-detail="Result: &lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot; ?&gt;&#xA;&lt;lbct:submit-ingate-data-response xmlns='(Had to remove link)' xmlns:xsi='(Had to remove link)' xmlns:lbct='(Had to remove link)' lbct:message-id='789637546382669' lbct:message-date='2014-01-23T06:37:32.0Z' lbct:facility-id='LBCT' lbct:complex-id='LBCT' lbct:sender='TOS'&gt;&#xA;  &lt;lbct:create-truck-visit-response&gt;&amp;lt;![CDATA[&amp;lt;argo:gate-response xmlns:argo=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;create-truck-visit-response&amp;gt;&amp;lt;truck-visit tv-key=&quot;52947590&quot; gos-tv-key=&quot;123&quot; tracking-tag-id=&quot;98765432&quot; is-internal=&quot;false&quot; next-stage-id=&quot;ingate&quot; status=&quot;OK&quot; gate-id=&quot;LBCT&quot; entered=&quot;2014-01-23T05:47:28&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;trucking-co id=&quot;WNWI&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;truck id=&quot;98765432&quot; tag-id=&quot;98765432&quot; license-nbr=&quot;D98765432&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;chassis-profile id=&quot;40&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;driver card-id=&quot;98765432&quot; driver-name=&quot;LICENSEABC&quot; /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/truck-visit&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/create-truck-visit-response&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/argo:gate-response&amp;gt;]]&amp;gt;&lt;/lbct:create-truck-visit-response&gt;&#xA;  &lt;lbct:process-truck-response&gt;&amp;lt;![CDATA[Unknown IN lane LANE20 for gate LBCT&amp;lt;argo:gate-response xmlns:argo=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xmlns:xsi=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot; xsi:schemaLocation=&quot;(Had to remove link)&quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;process-truck-response /&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/argo:gate-response&amp;gt;]]&amp;gt;&lt;/lbct:process-truck-response&gt;&#xA;&lt;/lbct:submit-ingate-data-response&gt;" />
  </messages>
  <submit-ingate-data-response xmlns:lbct="(Had to remove link)" xmlns="(Had to remove link)" xmlns:xsi="(Had to remove link)" lbct:message-id="789637546382669" lbct:message-date="2014-01-23T06:37:32.0Z" lbct:facility-id="LBCT" lbct:complex-id="LBCT" lbct:sender="TOS">
    <create-truck-visit-response>&lt;![CDATA[&lt;argo:gate-response xmlns:argo="(Had to remove link)" xmlns:xsi="(Had to remove link)" xsi:schemaLocation="(Had to remove link)"&gt;&lt;create-truck-visit-response&gt;&lt;truck-visit tv-key="52947590" gos-tv-key="123" tracking-tag-id="98765432" is-internal="false" next-stage-id="ingate" status="OK" gate-id="LBCT" entered="2014-01-23T05:47:28"&gt;&lt;trucking-co id="WNWI" /&gt;&lt;truck id="98765432" tag-id="98765432" license-nbr="D98765432" /&gt;&lt;chassis-profile id="40" /&gt;&lt;driver card-id="98765432" driver-name="LICENSEABC" /&gt;&lt;/truck-visit&gt;&lt;/create-truck-visit-response&gt;&lt;/argo:gate-response&gt;]]&gt;</create-truck-visit-response>
    <process-truck-response>&lt;![CDATA[Unknown IN lane LANE20 for gate LBCT&lt;argo:gate-response xmlns:argo="http://www.navis.com/argo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.navis.com/argo GateWebserviceResponse.xsd"&gt;&lt;process-truck-response /&gt;&lt;/argo:gate-response&gt;]]&gt;</process-truck-response>
  </submit-ingate-data-response>
</argo-response>
```

The only portion I require is the process-truck-response. I have been able to successfully pull the create-truck-visit out of it.

Here is the code i am currently using to try and decode and parse this:

```
string xmlString = textBox1.Text;
            string action = String.Empty;
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
            XNamespace lbctns = "http://www.lbct.com/TOS";

            XElement processTruckElement = xmlDoc.Document.Descendants(lbctns + "process-truck-response").FirstOrDefault();

            if (processTruckElement != null)
            {
                var decodedProccessTruckResponseElement = processTruckElement.Value;
                if (decodedProccessTruckResponseElement != null)
                {
                    decodedProccessTruckResponseElement = decodedProccessTruckResponseElement.Replace("<![CDATA[", "").Replace("]]>", "");
                }
                try
                {
                    var parsedSubmitMultipleElement = XElement.Parse(decodedProccessTruckResponseElement);

                }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are missing the header/declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` at the top of your XML snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The contents of the `process-truck-response` element doesn't consist of a valid XML fragment.

```
Unknown IN lane LANE20 for gate LBCT<argo:gate-response xmlns:argo="http://www.navis.com/argo" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.navis.com/argo GateWebserviceResponse.xsd"><process-truck-response /></argo:gate-response>
```

You're attempting to parse that out as an `XElement` and it fails (and rightly so).

You should verify that you have valid XML or at least handle cases where it contains content that you're not expecting.

Answer (score 1):

When XML tools say "invalid" (as opposed to "not well-formed") they generally mean that you've handed them the wrong kind of document. Check what this tool expects. In particular, since you haven't specified namespaces in the sample you've shown us, check whether it expects namespace bindings.